# basic qsort on string array crashes in qsort()

Tags: c, arrays, string, crash, qsort

I tried to create some basic code using qsort to sort an array of strings, but it crashes in qsort, according to gdb:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int pcmp(const void * a, const void * b)
{
  return strcmp(* (char * const *) a, * (char * const *) b);
}
int main()
{
  char pn[10][256];

  memset(pn, 0, sizeof(char) * 10 * 256);

  strcpy(pn[0], "hello");
  strcpy(pn[1], "TEST");
  strcpy(pn[2], "abc");
  strcpy(pn[3], "000000");

  qsort(pn, 4, sizeof (char *), pcmp);
}
```

Comment: Please see this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/23689916/2842896

Answer (score 1):

```
static int pcmp(const void * a, const void * b)
{
  return strcmp( (const char *) a, (const char *) b);
}
int main()
{
  char pn[10][256];

  strcpy(pn[0], "hello");
  strcpy(pn[1], "TEST");
  strcpy(pn[2], "abc");
  strcpy(pn[3], "000000");

  qsort(pn, 4, sizeof (char [256]), pcmp);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: By the way, what is the purpose of making pcmp static?

Comment: @DominikC Ask it him. I feel like I do is enough to cast a strcmp will I.

Comment: It's static cause that's how it was done in the example you get when you do "man qsort". I copy/pasted it sort of.

Answer (score 1):

```
qsort(pn, 4, sizeof (char *), pcmp);
```

You tell `qsort` that what you want to sort is an array of 4 `char*`, but

```
char pn[10][256];
```

actually, `pn` is an array of 10 `char[256]`. These things are layout-incompatible, and `qsort` interprets some bytes in the first of the `char[256]` as `char*`s. That's undefined behaviour, and not unlikely to cause a segmentation fault.

To fix it for this special case, you can change your comparison to

```
static int pcmp(const void * a, const void * b)
{
  return strcmp((const char *) a, (const char *) b);
}
```

and the invocation to

```
qsort(pn, 4, sizeof pn[0], pcmp);
```

Comment: thanks, I didn't know that there was some "layout ideas" internally. I thought it'd just parse strings, skip the zero bytes, parse next string, and not really care about the 256..